# Proving $\frac{1}{e}\cosh(2x)=\sum_{n=0,1,2,...}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)!}H_{2n}(x)$, where $H_{2n}(x)$ is the even order Hermite polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions, hermite-polynomials

> How can we prove the following relation $$\frac{1}{e}\cosh(2x)=\sum_{n=0, 1, 2, ...}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)!}H_{2n}(x)$$ where the $H_{2n}(x)$ is the even order *Hermite polynomial*?

I didn't get any clue by doing $$\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=0, 1, 2, ...}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)!}H_{2n}(x)$$Thanks beforehand.

Comment: This is an interesting identity. Where did you find it?

Comment: @K.defaoite My teacher told me to prove the relation, can you help me with this?

Comment: I will give it some thought. If I find a solution I will not post it in its entirety, but I will give you some hints to lead you to the solution on your own.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thank you so much.

Comment: that is a direct consequence of [the generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Generating_function) for H. polynomials

Comment: @G Cab Good observation, but I think it flows more easily from the approach mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @CuriousMind Have you made any progress?

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes I have solved it but in some other way, you can see my way in my answer, I have answered my own question as I got the solution, but thanks for helping me, I will do that by your method now. I didn't know that $\cosh(2x)$ and $\sinh(2x)$ satisfy the ODE $y''(x)=4 y(x)$. Your method seems interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint: $\cosh(2x)$ and $\sinh(2x)$ satisfy the ODE $y''(x)=4 y(x)$. Use the recurrence relation $H_{m}'(x)=2mH_{m-1}(x)$ and differentiate the series. If the series satisfies the same ODE, it is a linear multiple of $\sinh(2x)$ or $\cosh(2x)$. It is easy to show that it is indeed proportional to $\cosh(2x)$ using a simple parity argument. Then, all that is left is to show this proportionality constant is $1/e$. If you're still struggling after this hint, I'll add more. But give it a try first.

Answer (score 1):

**Answering my own question.**

---

We can proceed by putting $t=1$ in the known equation $$e^{2tx-t^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n(x).t^n}{n!}$$ we get $$e^{2x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n(x)}{n!}$$ and $$e^{2x-1}+e^{-2x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n(x)}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n(x)}{n!}(-1)^n$$ $$=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}(x)}{(2n)!}$$as odd terms will be cancelled, $$\implies \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{e}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}(x)}{(2n)!}$$ So ultimately we can get, $$\frac{1}{e}\cosh(2x)\:=\sum_{n=0, 1, 2, ...}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)!}H_{2n}(x)$$So we can prove it in this way also.

Comment: I considered the generating function approach but had a feeling it was going to get messy. Adding the $e^{-2x-1}$ is a clever trick I had completely missed. Nice solution.

Comment: Thanks, and I will try it using generating function

Comment: @K.defaoite Can you help me in this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3873810/777834